# Adding index to MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Very basic question - how do I add index to a column for a MySQL table?

```
CREATE TABLE housekeeper_stats 
(company_site_id int,    
company_id int,    
event_count int,    
host varchar(100),    
source varchar(100),    
source_type varchar(100));

mysql> alter table housekeeper_stats add index (company_id);
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'company_id' doesn't exist in table

mysql> create index company_idx_n1 on housekeeper_stats(company_id, company_site_id) using btree;

ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'company_id' doesn't exist in table


The documentation states:

ADD {INDEX|KEY} [index_name]
        [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option]
```

Don't know where am I going wrong?

thanks.

Comment: The SQL looks right. Are you sure the `CREATE TABLE` is successful and does what you need it to?

Comment: yes the table is created.

Comment: Given everything you've posted, it should (and does) work correctly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5958d Check the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE housekeeper_stats` and make sure you're connected to the right database of course :)

Comment: Well it still does not work on my MySQL DB. Just for academic purpose, I created another database & re-ran the whole process & it works (index created). It's the same DB creation process & same set of scripts, so puzzled what is wrong with my earlier DB.